# Use formula from table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have table with formulas:

```
ID Formulas
1 [A] > [B]
2 [A] > [B] + 1
```

I like to use the formula from the table in SELECT for example

```
   SELECT *
    FROM [Program].[dbo].[Data]
    WHERE 
[Home_Goals_Final] > [Away_Goals_Final] and 
[Total_History] >= @Total_History and
[Sum_Count_History] >= @Total_Histry
```

I'm trying to replace [Home_Goals_Final] > [Away_Goals_Final] with the formulas from the table for testing combinations 
I use SQL server 2014.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have to use dynamic SQL for this:

```
 declare @sql nvarchar(max);

set @sql = 'SELECT * FROM [Program_4].[dbo].[Edinica_2013-2014] WHERE @Where' ;

set @sql = replace(@sql, '@where',
                   (select ft.[Goals] from [Program_4].[dbo].[Test_Data_Varijabli_1] ft where ft.id = 5)
                  );

exec sp_executesql @sql;
```

I correct the query now its working

Comment: I try this but i don't have luck maybe more detailed description on the problem will help more

Comment: `replace (sql, '@where', ` <<< lost quotes around "where". It's a substring being replaces in `@sql` variable with the value from your table.

Comment: Now i have problem to implement or combine with the other variables from WHERE clause

Comment: @AleksandarNikoloski . . . You should be able to figure out how to adjust this answer.  You changed the question after I answer, and that is rude.  It could invalidate the answer and attract downvotes.

Comment: Sorry i.m knew to SQL Server and stack-overflow so i don't have any intentions to offend you. i'm very great full to your answer